# How to build a form with repeatable sections in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I need to build a form with repeatable sections that I can export as CSV. Is that possible with Cognito Forms?

My project in detail: I need to build a user registration and login form. After the user is logged in, he/she can use a form which is only visible for logged-in users.

In this form the user has to be able to add text fields, numbers and checkboxes. Also, this form collects individual user-meta (like company name and phone number) in a **repeatable** section as hidden fields.

The user should also be able to edit his own entries from front end after when he is logged in.

The admin should have the possibility to download the entire data as CSV. Every field has to become his own cell!

Is that possible in Cognito Forms?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms.

Cognito Forms supports repeating sections to capture repeating data.  It also supports exporting entry data to an Excel spreadsheet with one sheet containing the main entry data and additional sheets for each repeating section.  CSV export is not currently supported due to the requirement of exporting hierarchical data like this.

Anyone can sign up for free and create an organization account, but currently this is limited to one organization per user and one user per organization.  This limitation will disappear in the coming months as new features are added.